# Using Breadth-First Search instead of Bidirectional Search?

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, bidirectional-search

Is there any situation or search problem in which it would be better to use regular breadth-first search instead of bidirectional search?

Answer (score 1):

When your graph is oriented and your data structure only allow you to get efficiently the successors and not the predecessors.